Какое окончание должно быть у причастия "убрано" в предложении ниже? Речь только о единственном числе!
Убрано (или убрана?) 21 499 тонн зерна.
Ведь когда читаем, то получается "убрано 21 тысяча..."
В вопросе, который посчитали дубликатом моего, речь идет о выборе между единственным и множественным числом, а меня интересует только единственное.

Этот вопрос похож на: Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим (количественно-именное сочетание). Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обознач

Вариант 1. Убрана  21 499 тонн зерна.
Розенталь §184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)
 7. При словах тысяча, миллион, миллиард сказуемое обычно 
 согласуется по правилам согласования с подлежащими- 
 существительными (в роде и числе), например: Тысяча книг 
 поступила в школьную библиотеку; Миллион демонстрантов 
 заполнил площади и улицы столицы.

Справочная служба
 № 249774
 При отсчёте загрузки файла в браузере: осталОсь двацать 
 одна минута, или осталАсь двадцать одна минута? И какое 
 правило действует?
 ОТВЕТ. Сказуемое согласуется с числительным одна: осталась 
 двадцать одна минута.

Вариант 2. Убрано  21 499 тонн зерна.
Но безличное сказуемое также возможно. В этом случае имеется в виду единое целое:
Пример: На 3 августа намолочено 21212 тысяч тонн зерна.
3.  Форма единственного числа сказуемого употребляется 
при обозначении меры веса, пространства, времени и т.д., так 
как в этом случае имеется в виду единое целое, например: На 
покраску крыши ушло двадцать килограммов олифы; До конца 
пути оставалось пятнадцать километров; На выполнение всей 
работы понадобится шесть месяцев.


А вот, что думает Грамота: https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/315886

Вероятно, по аналогии: Пришли два человека. Выглядит некорректно и не по правилам.  Нет грамматической сочетаемости, нет безличного предложения с В.п. А что есть?

Согласна. Странный ответ Грамоты :-/
